# FragmentTransaction setTransition() for remove() doesn't change the transition previously set in replace()

Tags: android, android-fragments, transition, fragmenttransaction

So, first of all I create a new Fragment like this

```
ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
ft.replace(R.id.main_content_frame, cFr, "CARS");
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

And later I remove it like this

```
fm.popBackStack();
ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_NONE);
ft.remove(fm.findFragmentByTag("CARS")).commit();
```

**But** the close transition is done with the `TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN` animation (or its opposite by default, I think), and I clearly set `TRANSIT_NONE`.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
  public void mRemoveFragment(android.app.Fragment fragment){
    android.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
    ft.remove(fragment);
    ft.commit();
}
```

use this function to remove the fragment. Where in setCustomAnimation, you can give your scripts. I have currently used the default ones provided by android

Answer (score 3):

Try using a custom animation with the FragmentTransaction:

```
fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.frag_fade_in, R.anim.frag_fade_out, R.anim.frag_fade_in, R.anim.frag_fade_out);
```

Resources here :: [Custom animations for fragment transactions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#setCustomAnimations%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)